# SQL Union ALL using while / foreach

Tags: sql-server

I have a table for store table data from user, 
like this

```
______________________

ID |tableName | idUser 
______________________ 
1  | data1    | 1 
2  | data2    | 1 
3  | data3    | 2 
4  | data4    | 2
```

then sample for data1 n data2 table which have same field

> dbo.data1

```
______________________

ID |name      | amount 
______________________ 
1  | abc      | 1 
2  | def      | 1
```

> dbo.data2

```
______________________

ID |name      | amount 
______________________ 
1  | ghi      | 1 
2  | jkl      | 1
```

> result I want

```
______________________

ID |name      | amount 
______________________ 
1  | abc      | 1 
2  | def      | 1 
3  | ghi      | 1 
4  | jkl      | 1
```

how to get all union table for each user(**each user may have more than 2 table**)
so how to use the union all query to get union table for each idUser using foreach or while?

need help, thx

Comment: Smells like bad design...

Comment: yeah... but still need help to get this

Comment: Explain how do you have ids 1 through 4 in the desired outcome. Is it just a  row number? Do you need your desired output for only one user at a time?

Comment: yes, i need get the result from union all from 1 user at time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `Dynamic SQL`. You just need to generate a query of `UNION ALL`s and use `ROW_NUMBER` to assing a new `ID`.

```
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql1 = @sql1 + CHAR(10) +
'   SELECT * FROM ' + tableName + CHAR(10) +
'   UNION ALL'
FROM UserTable
WHERE IdUser = 1 -- @IdUser

--REMOVE LAST UNION ALL
SELECT @sql1 = SUBSTRING(@sql1, 1, LEN(@sql1) - 10)

SELECT @sql2 = 
'SELECT
    ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name),
    Name,
    Amount
FROM(' + @sql1 + ')t'

PRINT @sql2
EXEC(@sql2)
```

---

The result of `PRINT @sql2`:

```
SELECT
    ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name),
    Name,
    Amount
FROM(
    SELECT * FROM data1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM data2
)t
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can proceed like this also to get required result

```
declare @t table (ID INT,tablename varchar(10),Iduser Int)
insert into @t(ID,tablename,Iduser)values (1,'data1',1)
insert into @t(ID,tablename,Iduser)values (1,'data2',1)
insert into @t(ID,tablename,Iduser)values (1,'data3',2)
insert into @t(ID,tablename,Iduser)values (1,'data4',2)

declare @t1 table (ID INT,name varchar(10),amount Int)
insert into @t1(ID,name,amount)values (1,'abc',1)
insert into @t1(ID,name,amount)values (2,'def',1)



declare @t2 table (ID INT,name varchar(10),amount Int)
insert into @t2(ID,name,amount)values (1,'ghi',1)
insert into @t2(ID,name,amount)values (2,'jkl',1)

;WITH CTE AS 
(
select DISTINCT t.ID,tt.name AS name ,tt.amount as amount from @t t

 FULL JOIN @t1 tt on tt.ID = t.ID

 UNION ALL

 select DISTINCT t.ID,ttt.name AS name,ttt.amount as amount  from @t t

 FULL JOIN @t2 ttt on ttt.ID = t.ID
 )

 Select rank()OVER (PARTITION BY amount order by name)ID,C.name,C.amount  from CTE C ORDER BY name
```